# Add collection field to a form, that can render multiple 'prototypes'

Tags: javascript, forms, symfony

I have my code setup like in this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

The only thing that differs, is that I add tag fields through the change event of a select box (which holds a few tag types) instead of clicking the 'add tag' link.

What I like to add, is the option to add different form fields, according to the tag-type that is selected. (that is why I'm working with the change event instead of the add-tag link)

For example:

If I select tag-type 'simple', one form field should be rendered, being 'fieldName'

If I select tag-type 'advanced', two form fields should be rendered, being 'fieldName1' and 'fieldName2'

How can I do this? Should I define multiple prototypes? Or is there a more clever way?

Comment: You could use javascript to remove/hide the fields you dont want before you add them to the form.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

When I change the value of the select box, an ajax call is made of type "post".
That call executes an action in my controller. The action will build that same form again.

A PRE_SET_DATA event listener will take care of adding a form-field to the main form through a form-modifier function (based on the chosen value in the select box).

Last but not least: the POST_SUBMIT event listener that calls that same form-modifier function to avoid the "form can not contain any extra fields" error.